# Search for a (regex) match and then reformatting output in Linux

Tags: regex, shell, awk, command-line

My aim is to search for packages that start with (or consist of) a given string since this is not possible with the command `pacman` from Arch Linux. The easiest approach for finding packages is to execute `pacman -Sl |grep vivaldi`, where `vivaldi` is a package name, which will give:

```
herecura vivaldi 2.3.1440.60-1 [installed]
herecura vivaldi-ffmpeg-codecs 71.0.3578.98-1 [installed]
herecura vivaldi-snapshot 2.4.1468.4-1
```

Easy as it is, it has a flow: it searches for a given package name everywhere but the package name is always between first and second space.
Quite simple workaround is to the the following

`pacman -Sl | grep -P "(?:[a-z0-9-]+) vivaldi"`

The console will show output similar to the one below:

```
herecura vivaldi 2.3.1440.60-1 [installed]
herecura vivaldi-ffmpeg-codecs 71.0.3578.98-1 [installed]
herecura vivaldi-snapshot 2.4.1468.4-1
```

It will give (perhaps) the correct result which is the same as the one above. But there is another caveat: I'd like to to rearrange the output to to the form:

```
vivaldi 2.3.1440.60-1 [herecura] [installed] 
vivaldi-ffmpeg-codecs 71.0.3578.98-1 [herecura] [installed]
vivaldi-snapshot 2.4.1468.4-1 [herecura]
```

I'm quite close to it by executing the command:

```
pacman -Sl | grep -P "(?:[a-z0-9-]+) vivaldi" | awk '{print $2, $3, $4, $1}'

vivaldi 2.3.1440.60-1 [installed] herecura
vivaldi-ffmpeg-codecs 71.0.3578.98-1 [installed] herecura
vivaldi-snapshot 2.4.1468.4-1  herecura
vivaldi-snapshot-ffmpeg-codecs 72.0.3626.97-1  herecura
```

However, this is not a good approach as it uses `grep` with `awk` but `awk` solely will suffice because it also supports regexes (e.g. [see this blog post](https://blog.jpalardy.com/posts/skip-grep-use-awk/)).

This is all I get. Unfortunately, I cannot combine all I've written into one command (I'm planning to write an alias or a function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following(if I got it correctly), since you mentioned string will be in between 1st and 2nd space only so that becomes the 2nd field of line then. Now if we want to check for 2nd field's value I have put condition for 2nd field to check if current line's 2nd field is `vivaldi` then do printing.

```
pacman -Sl | awk '$2~/vivaldi/{print $2, $3, $4, $1}'
```

As per OP's comment aneed to wrap `$1` in `[` and `]` so adding following now.

```
pacman -Sl | awk '$2~/vivaldi/{print $2, $3, $4, "[" $1 "]"}'
```

Comment: Great it works! Very simple and elegant solution. How do I add [] to $1 to form [herecura]?

Comment: I wasn't clear enough. I'd like teh first argument $1 be surrounded with []. I used `pacman -Sl | awk '$2=="vivaldi"{print $2, $3, $4, "[",$1,"]"}'` but it gives me `vivaldi 2.3.1440.60-1 [installed] [ herecura ]`  which is close but there is a space after `[` and before `]`.

Comment: @menteith, it is because of `,` which indicates `print` to print a space, so no need to place it in case you DO NOT need it, simple :)

Comment: I've just noticed that your command lists only one line but `pacman -Sl | grep vivaldi` gives more (which means that there are more packages that start with vivaldi. AFAIK, this is because it searches for a given string (here `vivaldi` but it should search for strings that start with a name `vivaldi`).

Comment: No, it didn't help. There is only one package shown (vivaldi) but other packages (vivaldi-ffmpeg-codecs, vivaldi-snapshot, vivaldi-snapshot-ffmpeg-codecs) which pacman lists in other lines are not shown.

Comment: Great! Works like a charm.

Comment: @menteith, `$2=="vivaldi"` will match EXACT wors in 2nd field `vivaldi` since it could contain other stuff to I changed it to `$2~/vivaldi/`, done the trick.